# Issue with http:// and http://www

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, dns

I have an application which is hosted on a staging server. If I use my application by providing my credentials, I can open URL => `http://mysite.com`.

However, if I change the url to `http://www.mysite.com`, the site shows the login page again to request the credentials (which I have just provided).

Now on the staging server, if I type `http://mysite.com` in the address bar, I get sent to  `http://mysite.com`. But when I type google.com into the address bar, I get taken to `http://www.google.com`. How is this happening?

My question is: when my application goes live and I type `mysite.com`, will the url get converted to `http://www.mysite.com` or do I need to do something to convert the url to one containing `www`?

Answer (score 6):

You need to set up a forwarder to forward the `www` subdomain to the root domain.

Here's a few ways to do it:

- [Using Apache and mod_rewrite](http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/redirect-domain-www-subdomain.shtml).
- [Using IIS and URL Rewrite](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2009/11/27/iis-url-rewrite-rewriting-non-www-to-www.aspx).
- [Using IIS and some custom ASP.NET code](http://madskristensen.net/post/Add-or-remove-the-www-sub-domain.aspx).

Comment: I use a method very similar to the last option to do this on various sites.

Comment: My IIS is 6.0 
In this case will i be able to use the URL Rewriter?

Answer (score 3):

If you're unable to perform any of the URL rewriting methods recommended by [Skilldrick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063293/issue-with-http-and-http-www/2063302#2063302) then you will need to configure your authentication module to use the correct shared domain cookie.

If you are using Forms authentication this can be achieved in the web.config:

```
<forms name="name" 
       loginUrl="URL" 
       defaultUrl="URL"
       domain=".example.com">
</forms>
```

Note the leading period in the domain - this writes an authentication cookie that can be read from both example.com and www.example.com, meaning that you will now be logged in on both variations of the site.

That being said, the last example that Skilldrick gives works nicely, and should be fairly trivial for you to implement on your site.

Comment: ok.. let me try this. before that let me ask one doubt..what would be the name="name", what does this indicate? The loginurl and default url, are they both the same?

Answer (score 1):

You have several different issues you seem to be asking:

First off - why you get `http://www.google.com` when typing `http://google.com`:

This is because google are doing a redirect on the server side, so everyone going to `http://google.com` ends up at `http://www.google.com`/

You can do the same, by redirecting every call to `http://www.mysite.com` to `http://mysite.com`.

This can be achieved by using the `Response.Redirect` method, using a URL rewriting module or any of several ways.

Comment: I wouldn't issue a Response.Redirect as that only issues a Temporary Redirect (302), and some search engines don't like lots of those, it's better to use a method that produces a 301 permanent redirect as in the last example Skilldrick (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063293/issue-with-http-and-http-www/2063302#2063302) supplies.

Comment: if i take any site as an example 75%of them are adding www as prefix. I want to know whether its someting  that all are handling in the code behind or can be achieved by some tricks in IIS?

Comment: Many of them only have the domain with the www prefix registered, so attempting to go to the non www will fail. Others don't do any sort of redirect and both will work.

Answer (score 0):

Redirection from one URL to another can be handled in multiple ways. A couple are:

1. Meta refresh tag, hosted at http://mysite.com that contains something like:

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://www.mysite.com">
   ```
2. URL rewriting, for example with Apache (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html and http://www.widexl.com/tutorials/mod_rewrite.html might be places to look):

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mysite.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R,L]
   ```

   This would be used to externally redirect (HTTP 302) any host that doesn't match www.mysite.com to http://www.mysite.com.
   The same is likely also possible with IIS.